# DataModel for Workflow/Business Process Application

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

What should be the data model for a work flow application? Currently we are using an Entity Attribute Value based model in SQL Server 2000 with the user having the ability to create dynamic forms (on asp.net), but as the data grows performance is getting down and hard to generate report and worse if too many users concurrently query the data (EAV).

Answer (score 3):

As you have probably realized, the problem with an EAV model is that tables grow very large and queries grow very complex very quickly.  For example, EAV-based queries typically require lots of subqueries just to get at the same data that would be trivial to select if you were using more traditionally-structured tables.

Unfortunately, it is quite difficult to move to a traditionally-structured relational model *while simultaneously leaving old forms open to modification.*

**Thus, my suggestion:** consider *closing* changes on well-established forms and moving their data to standard, normalized tables. For example, if you have a set of shipping forms that are not likely to change (or whose change you could manage by changing the app because it happens so rarely), then you could create a fixed table and then copy the existing data out of your EAV table(s).  This would A) improve your ability to do reporting, B) reduce the amount of data in your existing EAV table(s) and C) improve your ability to support concurrent users / improve performance because you could build more appropriate indices into your data.

In short, think of the dynamic EAV-based system as a way to collect user's needs (they tell you by building their forms) and NOT as the permanent storage.  As the forms evolve into their final form, you transition to fixed tables in order to gain the benefits discussed above.

One last thing.  If all of this isn't possible, have you considered segmenting your EAV table into multiple, category-specific tables?  For example, have all of your shipping forms in one table, personnel forms in a second, etc.  It won't solve the querying structure problem (needing subqueries) but it will help shrink your tables and improve performance.

I hope this helps - I do sympathize with your plight as I've been in a similar situation myself!

Answer (score -1):

Typically, when your database schema becomes very large and multiple users are trying to access the same information in many different ways, [Data Warehousing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehousing), is applied in order to reduce major load on the database server. Unlike your traditional schema where you are more than likely using Normalization to keep data integrity, data warehousing is optimized for speed and multiple copies of your data are stored.

Comment: Clearly this is a joke answer meant to be funny. Hahaha.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the relational model of data.  It works.

Comment: That was a big help to the OP, I'm sure.